# Spring Boot deployed JAR not finding properties file in deployed directory

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have tried a few suggestions to get this to work but it still fails. I have deployed a jar file through spring boot to a remote location and need the properties file external to it in order to be able to make config changes at any time.

When the properties file is specified as below, the jar reads the file but only the file that was included in the IDE in /resources before building the jar. When I change the format to *(./application.properties)*, the jar does not find any file.

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
             throws Exception
  {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try {
            InputStream s =  
                getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties");
            if (s != null) prop.load(s);
            else {
                System.out.println("**NOT FOUND - configuration file:          
                **********************");LOGGER.info("Starting application.");
             ....
```

Tried running it like this as well to specify the location of the properties file to run:

```
java -jar -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar -Dspring.config.location=/config/application.properties 
       searchapp.jar
```

Please any ideas or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: What is your version of Spring Boot? `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties");` is not good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
java -jar -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar -Dspring.config.location=/config/application.properties searchapp.jar
```

to

```
java -jar -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar -Dspring.config.location=classpath:/config/application.properties searchapp.jar
```

or other way, by using absolute path (just for example, because I don't know your real absolute path)

```
java -jar -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar -Dspring.config.location=file:./config/application.properties searchapp.jar
```

Reference document: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

Comment: Let's me know the result, if it still does not work, I will revise command for you.

Comment: thank you for your response. I tried the last one and it's still reading the original config file used in the IDE.

Comment: If the last one did not work, notice that, the path in the above answer just is an example, it depend on your real config file path.

Comment: Yes, tried the first and last; it still reads the config in the IDE prior to building jar. Is there a way I can override that or should I manually put the remote path to config before deploying?

Comment: What is your build tool? Maven or Gradle? You use build tool for build JAR file, then run command, don't **build by IDE then run by command line**.

Comment: Maven; but building the jar through the IDE as Maven build (Clean package) is the same isn't it?